# facebook api - profile pictures and rate limits.. what is the correct practice?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Having an issue where facebook api is sporadically returning "broken" images for profile pictures.. and then eventually going back to normal.

I'm using facebook login via their javascript/php SDK's..  That is working, and once the user is logged in,  at various points around my site, I render their profile picture using an img tag ie:

```
<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $fbid;?>/picture?access_token=<?php echo $facebook->getAccessToken();?>'>
```

It works most of the time, but at some points I'll start getting "broken" images for a while.. and then maybe 10-20 minutes later it will all start working again.

Perhaps I'm being rate-limited (as per   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/ )    ----   but this is just a dev site that only I am accessing, so there's not an incredible amount of requests.

How am I "supposed" to be doing this?   Am I supposed to be retrieving the picture once from facebook and then storing it on my server rather than constantly going back to their servers?  or am I doing something wrong with the access token?  or could this be something else?

Comment: You don't need an access_token for catching the profil image of a user.